# NSLayoutConstrains not working when added Programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add UITextField in a UITableViewCell Programatically,this textfield should have consistent view across all iOS Devices(8 Pixels Padding from all the corners i.e cell.contentView).

So I have written code snippet:

```
UITableViewCell * cell2 = [tableView         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"startLocation"];

    if (cell2 == nil)
    {
        cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:@"startLocation"];
    }

    UITextField *endLoc = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8,8,340,28) ];

    endLoc.placeholder = @"Start Location";

    [cell2.contentView addSubview:endLoc];

    [cell2.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSLayoutConstraint *textLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: endLoc attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell2.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:8.0f];


    NSLayoutConstraint *textRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: endLoc attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell2.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:8.0f];

    [cell2.contentView addConstraint:textLeftConstraint];
    [cell2.contentView addConstraint:textRightConstraint];

    return cell2;
```

I have added this snippet in tableview delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath

This is the code I know so far..Am I missing anything ?

The final output I want to get is something as described below:

Two Text Fields - Start Location and Start Time.
Constraints for Start Location : 8px from left and should be 20 px from Start Time (width should be greater than 70%).
Constraints for Start Time : 20px left from start Location text field and should be 8px right from right corner(width should be approx. 20-25%).

this cell's view should be consistent across all the devices. Start Location text will be placed 8px from left corner and will occupy atleast 70% of width.
Any help.

Comment: USe masonry for addding constraints

Comment: I am new to ios Development..Can you please be more specific. masonry ?